# Dominio visible en google

Tags: wordpress, seo, google-search-console

He creado un blog en wordpress, solo tengo una entrada y el inicio, viendo alguno tutoriales he dado de alta mi dominio en freewebsubmission y en searchconsole.

Cuando busco mi dominio en google, por ejm:

```
dominio.es -> no me sale en la página de resultados
dominio.es/mi-primera-entrada -> si sale en la página de resultados
```

NOTA: utilizo tb el plugin yoast, he dado de alta el sites map en google

¿por qué no me sale en google cuando busco midominio.es?

Comment: Como te ha dicho google tarda en indexar los dominios, a veces demasiado, para comprobar si tu dominio está indexado o no puedes buscar el dominio desde google con site, por ejemplo: site:misitio.com, de esta forma podrás ver si tu sitio aparece en el buscador o no.

Answer (score 1):

Google tarda cierto tiempo en mostrar una nueva página en su buscador. Por eso, lo mejor es tener paciencia. A veces tarda varios meses, incluso de 3 a 6 meses. Cuando se trata de páginas web con un dominio nuevo, normalmente Google se lo toma con calma.

Pero ante todo, el dominio no lo es todo. Lo importante es el contenido de la web y sus palabras claves para que haya una buena indexación. No por registrar un dominio voy a aparecer cada vez que busco el dominio.

Si tienes una sola entrada, empieza a escribir más entradas con sentido; dale tiempo a la máquina y demuestra a google que ofreces algo interesante y coherente. 
No hay una fórmula mágica para aparecer en las búsquedas, si la hubiese todos estarían arriba del todo. Sobre todo, no te desesperes.

Comment: entiendo eso, pero pensaba que cuando buscabas un dominio concreto en google, lo normal es que te aparezca, me parece raro que la entrada sino pero el dominio a secas no

Comment: Es google,... y eso significa que hay muchos entresijos en el algoritmo.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer una consulta en google sobre la indexación de un dominio o URL te recomiendo hacer la siguiente consulta en google

> info:dominio.com

Ahí verás si tu web está o no indexada en el buscador de google. Una vez indexada la web ya podrás empezar a indexar artículos y mejorar la firmeza del dominio para así conseguir mejores posiciones en los resultados de búsquedas.

En WordPress te recomiendo que compruebes que esté desactivada la opción de `

> Disuadir motores de búsquedas

localizada en

> Ajustes > Lectura

Si estando dicha opción desactivada aún no apareces en google con la anterior búsqueda, paciencia, google necesita revisar tu web antes de indexarla!